# How to retrieve all nodes from an xml with a given xpath scala

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

Assuming I have an XML like this one

```scala
val myXml: NodeSeq = scala.xml.Utility.trim(<a>
    <b>
      <c>Mom</c>
    </b>
    <b>
      <c>Dad</c>
    </b>
    <notb>
      <c>foo</c>
      <c>bar</c>
    </notb>
  </a>)
```

How can I retrieve "Mom" and "Dad" from an xpath such as this one? `"b/c"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a foldLeft, one can retrieve all elements

```
"b/c"
  .split('/')
  .foldLeft(myXml)((node, path) => node \ path)
```

Output:

```
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = <c>Mom</c><c>Dad</c>
```

One can even use "wildcards" to match every children

```
"_/c"
  .split('/')
  .foldLeft(myXml)((node, path) => node \ path)
```

Output:

```
res1: scala.xml.NodeSeq = <c>Mom</c><c>Dad</c><c>foo</c><c>bar</c>
```

Comment: `_` is not a "wildcard" for XPath. This is just Scala.